# Saving the search path in Matlab is not working

Tags: matlab, settings, search-path

I want to permanently add a folder to Matlab's search path. I follow the steps on [this page](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/what-is-the-matlab-search-path.html): Set path - Add with subfolders...
Then I click save to save the path for future sessions (that is, to include the folder that I just added).
However, upon reopening Matlab, the added folder is no longer in the search path and I need to add it again.
Why is my method not working?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The fact that Matlab did not recall my settings was caused by network settings, so not by Matlab itself.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with this manner of setting a default search path, but I'll share the method that I use with you in hopes that that resolves your problem as well.

When MATLAB starts it automatically looks for a file named 'startup.m' in its default search path and executes that file. What I do is create the file 'startup.m' in MATLAB's default folder and put the following in that file.

```
addpath('C:\My Folder')
```

For personal convenience I also add the following lines of code, but they are not necessary for setting the search path.

```
cd('C:\My Folder')
disp('Changed current directory to C:\My Folder')
```

While this doesn't directly answer your question, I hope this method serves as an alternative.